# Can an entire, non-constant function map $\mathbb{C}$ to a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

Can an entire, non-constant function map the complex plane to a proper subset of the complex plane?  And, by what theorem?

Comment: Think about $e^z$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, but only just. This is [Picard's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), which says that there is at most one point that is not in the range of a non-constant entire function $f$. The canonical counterexample for missing a point is $e^z$, which maps $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.